# How to get the current value of tqdm?

Tags: python, tqdm

How do I get an updated `tqdm.n`?
This code seems to work:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
pbar = tqdm(range(10000))
for i in pbar:
     pbar.refresh()
     print 'pbar', pbar.n
```

Do I have to call `tqdm.refresh()`?

Comment: Please tell, why does it seem to work? And why wouldn't it work? From my experience, you do not need to `refresh()`, this only refreshes the displayed progress bar. But the iteration number seems to be updated only every ten iterations. Is that why you ask for an updated `tqdm.n`?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
from tqdm import tqdm
class TqdmSpy(tqdm):
    @property
    def n(self):
        return self.__n

    @n.setter
    def n(self, value):
        print(value, self.total)
        self.__n = value
```

Comment: instead of `print` you can call your function. So it will act as callback. On every tqdm iteration your function will be called with current n as parameter

Comment: What did not work, actually? Also, there's a dedicated `tqdm.write()` to print output without interfering with the progress bar.